# Can't grant all privileges to root in MySQL 5.7. Syntax error

Tags: mysql

This one is really baffling. I hope I'm not doing something stupid, but it just doesn't make sense. I installed a fresh MySQL 5.7 on Ubuntu, logged in locally to mysql as root and ran the following:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Success!

Next, I ran this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

No bueno. This resulted in the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION' at line 1
```

WTF? I've been running that command on MySQL servers for 2 years. Why didn't it work? As any good little developer would do, I decided to RTM. Here's the example given in the 5.7 manual (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-users.html):

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'finley'@'%'
->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Am I taking crazy pills? Except for the username, that's exactly what I did. This should just work, right??? There's a baffling lack of other people on the Internet reporting this problem, so I assume I must just be glossing over something obvious, but I'm 2 hours deep into this and just plain can't figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I thought that this was already done when you installed MySQL. What does the output of `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'%'` show?

Comment: @gr1zzlybe4r I think the default user is `root@localhost`, not `root@%`.

Comment: No, MySQL only sets that up for root@localhost by default. I'm not able to log into the server until tomorrow at this point, but I'll post the SHOW GRANTS output tomorrow morning.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you inadvertently typed a Unicode character that looks like `*` but isn't the real ASCII character, or maybe some other non-printing character.

Answer (score 7):

After kicking my own brain for several minutes, remembered that, by default in a new install, the user "root@%" doesn't  exists and must be created separately.

This must work for you:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword';    
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%'  WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Came across this when trying to follow instructions for remote access to bitnami mysql vm.  Worked great thanks. https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/infrastructure/mysql/administration/connect-remotely/

Answer (score 2):

on mysql syntax has been changed

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```